# Info about backtracking control verbs

Tags: php, regex, pcre, backreference

I been searching info about this verbs,
There is not much info about that, i only found info like this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) but is not about the verbs, they just mentioned.
I googled it, but not so lucky,
i just found examples from here(stack overflow) applying it.
But is not exaplained.

I wanna know if they are available for PCRE,
cuz i use PHP and i saw one example about this but i dont know about it.
I wanna know if exist info, a list o verbs, etc,
thank you

Examples (*ANY)(*FAIL)

Answer (score 1):

You can look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html).

The two constructs that directly change backtracking are **Atomic group** and **Posessive(super greedy) quantifier**.

P.S. Sorry if i misunderstood the question